# Is having a gas stove with a recirculating hood a bad idea？

Tags: kitchens, hood, microhood, gas-stove

We currently have an electric stove and a recirculating hood (microhood), and we don't like either. Ideally, we'd go for a gas stove and a proper venting hood. However, adding a venting hood is tricky in my house, so I'm thinking of converting the stove to gas, for a partial improvement.

Is that a bad idea? I had that in an NYC apartment years ago, but all houses I've been to seem to pair a gas stove with a venting hood.

Comment: Unless a bad cook, electric stoves should only have food cooking smells.  With a gas stove you also have fuel burning plus the chance of CO, stuff I would like vented outside.

Comment: If you're stuck with that hood and you already have power for the range, consider the induction option. Apparently venting gas ranges is not required by code, but that seems foolhardy to me...

Comment: My house was built with a gas stove and a recirculating hood (90s UK, major housebuilding firm) so it's not a ridiculous idea. But one of the things we had to have when redoing the kitchen was an actual extractor. Which was easy because the recirculating hood was on an outside wall.

Comment: This question is a matter of opinion. "Bad" is subjective. I will say that natural gas combustion byproduct is known to degrade indoor air quality, and may be a lung cancer risk factor. I tend to run my exhausting fan on low when I'm baking or cooking with multiple burners or for a long time. Also know that natural gas is a fossil fuel, so consider your environmental impact.

Comment: Burning gas also makes a lot of water vapor (in addition to steam from cooking), not getting rid of it can cause humidity/mold problems...

Comment: A recirculating hood does not create any new hazard -- would your question be better stated "Is having a gas stove _without a venting hood_ a bad idea?"

Comment: You have the cause and effect reversed. The actual situation is that having a gas range is a cause of needing a venting hood. Getting a gas stove will not make your recic hood perform better. What will make your hood give a  better result is to not overheat oil or shorting an make smoking grease. Getting a gas range will be an expensive and uneeded change.

Comment: @JimStewart   As not a chef I will probably agree with you.   I have also read  that chefs/good cooks prefer gas, so unneeded is opinion.  Will be expensive if electric is still good/just want gas instead.

Comment: Latest trend is electric indutction. No combustion fumes and higher percent of heat goes into the food so kitchen is more comfortable. My niece in Germany cooks on induction. Every system has it benefits and limitations. Induction allows very rapid change in heat of a surface burner. Advise you not to buy a gas stove thinking it will solve your venting problem. If you want to experiment with induction get an 1800 W 120 V countertop model for about $100. You do have to have pans than have a bottom that a magnet sna;ps onto. Oven in an induction range would be ele resistance.

Comment: If you already have an electric range that is reasonably satisfactory to you, overwhelming probabliity is that you will not benefit from changing to a gas stove.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I want gas because gas is better for my cooking style while at the same time I’m stuck with a recirculating hood. Sounds like it can be a bad move.

Comment: Induction behaves much more like gas heat than other electric stoves, and has advantages of its own. Biggest disadvantage is cost, which may include getting new cookware if you have old non-magnetic stainless steel or aluminum. See past answers about inductive cooktops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of fact that gas stoves put combustion byproducts in to the air. The lack of requirement for an exhaust fan to use them in the house is an outcome of lobbying by the gas industry. [The gas industry wanted to increase sales](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/23812229-aga-monthly-196901#document/p2/a2351681), so they pushed gas stoves hard starting in the 60s. It's also been established for many years that byproducts of gas production [have negative health outcomes](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00022470.1970.10469445).

But is it bad enough to do something about? That's a matter of opinion. My opinion is that I wouldn't add a gas stove anywhere unless I could also add a suitable exhaust hood. Of course, I also lived in an apartment for nine years with a gas stove and no hood.

So: is having a gas stove with no exhaust a bad idea? Yes. Is it a bad enough idea that you shouldn't do it? That's out of scope for this site. You make your own call there.

In my home, I spent my own money to switch from gas to induction. I'd never go back. I also have a standalone portable gas burner, because it's necessary for some specialized forms of cooking. Life is a compromise.

Comment: In certain cities restaurants are being required to change to induction to protect the health of their employees.

Comment: Thanks. Induction is new to me. I’ll look into it.

Comment: @JimStewart haven't heard of that for restaurants. They usually have great kitchen ventilation so it should be less of a concern there than at home, though for sure volume of exposure matters.

Comment: @qweruiop induction doesn't work well for woks or directly grilling things, but it's great for most everything else. I love the ability my cooktop has to hold a temperature even as I boil off water or add cool ingredients, too. It will add or decrease power as the temperature of the pan changes, when on one of the settings.

Comment: If the  incoming electricity cables are fat enough, induction can be great in commercial kitchens. It helps with air quality and the unsafe temperatures they can reach at times (because it delivers heat more efficiently into the food). But retrofitting isn't common yet, except where there's no mains gas supply - having gas delivered is far more expensive and shifts the economics

Comment: Heat in commercial kitchens with large gas cooktops is too high. INduction has solved that.https://youtu.be/SGBP3sG3a9Y?si=6EmIG2wbSM9Iz5Zl

Comment: Some very high end induction ranges (cooktop and oven(s) in one unit) do specify a 50 A circuit, but most spec 40 A just like  a modern electric resistance range. An induction cooktop would generally be less. A Vietnamese woman of my acquaintance is very happy with her Bosch inducn cooktop. I have not asked her if she has a special wok.

Comment: There are special induction woks. People have Opinions about them, though.